# Haskell intersection with duplicates

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and this has to be quite simple, but I have been searching the net for an hour without finding a convenient answer.

What I want is a function that returns an 'intersection' of two lists: a list of the elements that exists in both lists, taking account of duplicates.

I thought the function `intersect` would be what I wanted but, as stated in the docs, if the first list contains duplicates, so will the result. E.g.:

```
[1,2,2,2,3,4] `intersect` [6,4,4,2,2] == [2,2,2,4]
```

This is not what I want, since [2,2,2,4] isn't a part of [6,4,4,2,2] because there are only two 2's in that list. My desired result is:

```
[1,2,2,2,3,4] `intersect` [6,4,4,2,2] == [2,2,4]
```

How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One inefficient way is

```
intersect' xs ys = xs \\ (xs \\ ys)
```

For example

```
[1,2,2,2,3,4] \\ [6,4,4,2,2]   == [1,2,3]
[1,2,2,2,3,4] \\ [1,2,3]       == [2,2,4]
```

And

```
[6,4,4,2,2]   \\ [1,2,2,2,3,4] == [6,4]
[6,4,4,2,2]   \\ [6,4]         == [4,2,2]
```

From http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html :

In the result of `xs \\ ys`, the first occurrence of each element of `ys` in turn (if any) has been removed from `xs`. Thus

```
(xs ++ ys) \\ xs == ys.
```