# Fast length of an intersection with duplicates in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, optimization

I'm writing a mastermind solver, and in an inner loop I calculate the length of the [intersection with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332815/haskell-intersection-with-duplicates) of two lists. Right now the function I have is

```
overlap :: Eq c => [c] -> [c] -> Int
overlap [] _ = 0
overlap (x:xs) ys
    | x `elem` ys = 1 + overlap xs (delete x ys)
    | otherwise = overlap xs ys
```

Is it possible to make this faster? If it helps, the arguments to `overlap` are short lists of the same length, at most 6 elements, and the `c` type has less than 10 possible values.

Comment: Not in general, but you can sometimes ensure that both lists are ordered and thus boost performance...

Comment: Unfortunately, one of the lists is coming from a user. I could sort them first, but I doubt it would be worth the cost.

Comment: sorting can be done in O(n log n) whereas your comparison is done in O(n^2)

Comment: At least make it tail recursive (since your return type is flat).  And you should benchmark--sorting may still be worth it.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try it. But keep in mind that `n==6`, so asymptotic time doesn't really matter.

Comment: @AnschelSchaffer-Cohen: in case *n=6*, I don't see much benefit to optimize this function anyway. Profiling in general focuses on the parts that require a significant amount of computational effort.

Comment: @CommuSoft: n=6, but this function gets run about a million times, it's the bottleneck of the program.

Comment: @AnschelSchaffer-Cohen: but in that case, you can do the sorting only *once*, and thus repeat the intersection in linear time. Linear time is in many cases a significant boost over quadratic time.

Comment: You probably have a specific type `c` in mind: try using directly that instead of using a polymorphic function. Or alternatively use a `SPECIALIZE` GHC pragma.

Comment: @chi: My understanding is I can just SPECIALIZE a top-level function and GHC will specialize anything it calls within the module. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure about when GHC specializes. Check the GHC Core to see if that's actually done in your case. Or add a SPECIALIZE pragma and see if it makes any difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is (almost) impossible to boost the performance of such algorithm: in order to remove duplicates in two *unordered* and *unhashable* lists, can be done in *O(n^2)*.

In general, you can however boost performance with the following conditions (per condition, a different approach):

- If you can for instance ensure that for each list you create/modify/..., the order of the elements is maintained; this can require some engineering. In that case, the algorithm can run in O(n).

  In that case you can run it with:

  ```
  --Use this only if xs and ys are sorted
  overlap :: Ord c => [c] -> [c] -> Int
  overlap (x:xs) (y:ys) | x < y = overlap xs (y:ys)
                        | x > y = overlap (x:xs) ys
                        | otherwise = 1 + overlap xs ys
  overlap [] _ = 0
  overlap _ [] = 0
  ```

  In general sorting of a list can be done in *O(n log n)* and is thus more efficient than your *O(n^2)* overlap algorithm. The new overlap algorithm runs in *O(n)*.
- In case `c` is ordered, you might use a [`Data.Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Set.html) as well. In that case you can use the [`fromList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Set.html#g:11) method that runs in *O(n log n)* to create a TreeSet for the two lists, then use the [`intersection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Set.html#g:5) function to calculate the intersection in *O(n)* time and finally use the [`size`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Set.html#g:3) function to calculate the size.

  ```
  --Use this only if c can be ordered
  overlap :: Ord c => [c] -> [c] -> Int
  overlap xs ys = size $ intersection (fromList xs) (fromList ys)
  ```

Comment: I will benchmark both of these ideas some time in the next 24 hours. Asymptotic time complexity is probably irrelevant when the lists are so short, so I wouldn't want to guess one way or the other what will be fastest.

Comment: @AnschelSchaffer-Cohen: I think optimization is a bit (sorry for the word) *useless* if you are dealing with such small lists anyway. You will not lose significant time over these in general.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using same `ys` for multiple `xs`?

If yes, you can try to calculate hash values for each element in `ys` and match by this value, but keep in mind that calculating hash needs to be faster then 6 comparisons.

If either of those is `Ord` you may also sort it earlier, and verify only necessary part of `ys`.

However, if you need fast random access lists aren't the best structure, you should probably take a look at `Data.Array` and `Data.HashMap`

Comment: I am using the same `ys` for multiple `xs`. But comparison is cheap (in practice `c` is `Int`), so I don't think hashing will help.